# How can I retrofit an LED to indicate "charging"?

Tags: led, battery-charging

I have a device that, for some reason, does not have any indicator that it is charging.  So if the connection isn't good, you don't know that the device never charged until you use it and it dies much earlier than expected.  I would like to add an LED to indicate that it is charging in some form or fashion and I'm looking for a simple way to do it.

The device is relatively simple and was designed in the 80s.  I'd rather not modify the PCB as it will take time to do it properly, and the PCB has thick conformal coating that I would need to remove before probing, modifying, or reverse engineering.

Instead, the battery, switches, and fuses all have cables that are easy to cut and crimp to add my circuit.  It has a [12V lead-acid battery](https://www.batteriesplus.com/productdetails/powps=1270f) and an 18V wall wart that plugs in.  My guess is the 18V is applied directly to the 12V battery, and it charges with the [constant-voltage method](https://www.power-sonic.com/blog/how-to-charge-a-lead-acid-battery/) that the battery manufacturer recommends.

I'm wondering how you would go about adding a simple circuit to indicate charging is taking place.

My only idea is to add an LED with a current-limiting resistor in parallel with the battery so the LED turns on at about 18V.  When the charger is plugged in, the 18V will charge the battery and a small current will light the LED.  This will indicate that the charger is properly connected to the device, and I can assume the battery is charging.

Pro: very simple as it requires 1 LED, 1 resistor, and a few cuts and crimps to the cables.  And I guess I need to drill a hole in the enclosure so the LED can stick out and "indicate" to the user that it is charging.  So I need an LED that is chassis mount or something.

Con: Technically, it doesn't indicate charging, but just the presence of the charging voltage.  So, if a crimp is bad, the LED may light up but the battery may not be charging.

Con: The LED will draw a small current from the battery when the charger is not connected and the device is switched OFF.  I assume it will be negligible as the current-limiting resistor will be chosen for 18V, not 12 V.

Anyway, I wanted to ask the community before I sink my time trying to do something stupid.  Will this work?  Is there something better?

Comment: If you put the LED in parallel with the battery, it will light up as long as there is voltage in the battery, regardless of the charger being connected or not. There is not enough details about the circuit to give any suggestions where a LED could be connected.

Comment: The circuit is an 18V charger connected to a 12V battery through a connector.  So I can connect or disconnect the charger.  If I power the device on, the switch disconnects the charger from the battery.  So with the switch OFF, we can completely disregard the PCB.  It really is just an 18V charger and a 12V battery.

Comment: What are the specifications of the 18V 'wallwart'?  Can you measure the voltage and/or current on it when the device is charging and not charging?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to measure the current through the wall wart. A simple current sensor and comparator could light an LED if current more than a certain threshold is drawn.

Comment: The wall wart is 18V and 2A.  I just measured the current while charging and it is only 200mA.  There was no measurable voltage drop from the wall wart being under load.

Comment: I forgot about zener diodes.  What about a 13V zener diode in series with the LED and resistor I proposed above.  This would solve the problem that Justme mentioned.  Otherwise, I think Hearth's suggestion of a comparator is probably what I would have to do to actually detect charging current.

Comment: I would be keen to know whether the wall wart is AC or DC.  With AC, tricks are possible.

Comment: I would start by hacking in a voltmeter in parallel with the battery, and making observations about battery voltage during charging and discharging times.  For a job like this I would use a simple UXCELL analog voltmeter, cheap and mostly reliable, but most importantly, doesn't drain the battery.  They also sell a variety of modular digital voltmeters which will take some power to run their digital LED outputs.

Comment: If you ever see anywhere near 18V across a 12V battery, then it's either very dead, or already on fire.

Comment: Could you tell I what you have between the  wall-wart (18V - **Question**: AC or DC?) and your Lead acid battery ? You measured charging current as ~200mA, but what is the battery voltage for that - and what is the battery size - either in Ah or physical dimensions. This would help us to prepare a more adequate answer for your needs. For example, if there is a circuit between Wall-wart and battery, **current** could be measure *before* and battery voltage should be measured after it. But the information asked is important to be minimalist and useful.

Comment: "My guess is the 18V is applied directly to the 12V battery, and it charges with the constant-voltage method that the battery manufacturer recommends." -- Disagree.  My guess is that it is a "Taper Current Charging" method in the same document.  This is very common.  Sometimes, the transformer core size is the only thing limiting the current into the battery.  Very low cost and very simple.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flAe5E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should work. You may need to use a transistor that can handle the charging current in the base. And you lose about 700 mV (or up to 1.5V) for B-E voltage.

(edit) R3 simulates current limiting of the charger (V1). M1, with V2, simulate connection and removal of the battery.

[image: Charger voltages]
[image: Charger currents]

Comment: Why the knee-jerk downvote? Please explain what you think is wrong with this approach, other than I did not include whatever sort of current limiting is built into the 18V charger.

Comment: Seems overly complex.  What are the purposes of R3, M1, and V2?

Comment: R3 simulates current limiting of the charger (V1). M1, with V2, simulate connection and removal of the battery.